# Is the set of vectors S a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m in an undergrad linear algebra course but am stuck on this problem. There are many examples here related to proving a vector is a subspace, but I haven’t found one quite like what is below.

*Consider the set of vectors S given by:*

$$S = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}  4u+v−5w \\ 12u+6v−6w \\  4u+4v+4w \end{bmatrix} : u, v, w \in \mathbb{R} \right\} $$

*Is S a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$? If so, explain why, give a basis for the subspace and find its dimension.*

We’ve reviewed the subspace test in class:

1. $\vec{0} \in S$
2. Given $\vec{u}, \vec{v}  \in S$, $\vec{u} + \vec{v}
       \in S$
3. Given *k* scalar, $\vec{u} \in S, k\vec{u} \in S$

...but we’ve only applied this in a proof so far (as opposed to a system of equations). At this point I’ve only found that the set is *not* linearly independent. Reduced row echelon yields:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2 \\ 0&1&3 \\  0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

which will be useful for the dimension/basis. But I am still not following how to solve the first part. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to dig in to the claims. Can you pick $u,v,w$ to exhibit $0\in S$? How about the others? What work have you done to attempt to verify the conditions you need?

Comment: By definition, $S$ is the column space of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{4&1&-5\\12&6&-6\\ 4&4&4}.
$$
Proving that your $S$ is a subspace is not much different from the general proof that the column space of a matrix is indeed a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer for this. The professor noted *S* can be written as a liner combination:

$$ u\begin{bmatrix}  4\\12\\4 \end{bmatrix}  + v \begin{bmatrix}  1\\6\\4 \end{bmatrix} + w \begin{bmatrix}  -5\\-6\\4 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, the set *S* can also be thought of a span since each vector can be multiplied by some arbitrary coefficient:

$$ span\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}  4\\12\\4 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  1\\6\\4 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  -5\\-6\\4 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

And [as the theorem goes](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-S.html#theorem-SSS), a span *is* a subspace. Therefore, the set *S* is a subspace.